# Option Selection Value dont word

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Eg "sishane" is selected, I want the adres div picture to come but it does not work

LİVE CODE:https://jsfiddle.net/yqnork11/

```
<select required id="otopark" name="otopark" type="text" placeholder="Otopark" class="form-control">
<option disabled selected value>Otopark Seçiniz</option>
<option value="sishane1">Şişhane</option>
<option value="buyuk1">Büyükçekmece</option>
<option value="Zeytinburnu">Zeytinburnu</option>
<option value="Kadıköy">Kadıköy</option>
<option value="Bayatpazarı">Bayatpazarı</option>
<option value="Kemalpaşa">Kemalpaşa</option>
<option value="Vardar">Vardar</option>
<option value="Aydın">Aydın</option>
</select><br>

<div id="adres"></div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#otopark").change(function(){
var seçilen = $('#otopark option:selected').text();
if (seçilen == "sishane1") $('#adres').html("<imgsrc='images/adres/sishane.png' />");
else if (seçilen == "buyuk1") $('#adres').html("<img src='images/adres/sishane.png' />");
}
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

I see at least four errors:

1. In this line:

   ```
   var seçilen = $('#otopark option:selected').text();
   ```

   you're getting the **text** of the option (`"Şişhane"`), not its value (`"sishane1"`). Get the value from the select:

   ```
   var seçilen = $('#otopark').val();
   ```
2. Neither your call to `change` nor your call to `ready` is properly terminated. You're missing

   ```
       );
   });
   ```

   from the end of your script.
3. `$('#adres').html("<imgsrc='images/adres/sishane.png' />");` won't work. You're missing a space after `<img`.
4. Other than the missing space (#3 above), both of your conditions append the same image, `images/adres/sishane.png`.

Comment: @KadirAkyüz: Looking past the first error, I see at least three more I've flagged up above. With due respect, I recommend doing more debugging, paying attention to errors in the web console, etc. before posting questions. Programming is an exercise in *details*. The above are almost all the result of not paying attention to details.

Answer (score 0):

it should be

```
var seçilen = $(this).val();
```